# Add line with datasets at top of table (stargazer R package)

Tags: r, latex, stargazer

With the code below I manage to produce the first table below. But...

```
swiss2 <- swiss[1:20,]

m1 <- lm(Fertility ~ Agriculture, data = swiss)
m2 <- lm(Fertility ~ Examination, data = swiss)
m3 <- lm(Infant.Mortality ~ Education, data = swiss)
m4 <- lm(Infant.Mortality ~ Catholic, data = swiss)
m5 <- lm(Fertility ~ Agriculture, data = swiss2)
m6 <- lm(Fertility ~ Examination, data = swiss2)
m7 <- lm(Infant.Mortality ~ Education, data = swiss2)
m8 <- lm(Infant.Mortality ~ Catholic, data = swiss2)

stargazer(m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8,
          type = "latex",
          out="./table.tex",
          omit.stat=c("LL","ser","f","adj.rsq"), 
          font.size="tiny", 
          column.labels = c("(M1)", "(M2)", "(M3)", "(M4)", "(M5)", "(M6)", "(M7)", "(M8)"), 
          model.names = FALSE,
          model.numbers = FALSE,
          star.cutoffs = c(0.05, 0.01, 0.001),
          dep.var.labels = c("Outcome 1", "Outcome 2", "Outcome 1", "Outcome 2"))
```

[image]

...I would rather like to produce this table below. The only difference is that there is a row instead of the row "Dependent variable:" with two columns that indicate the relevant datasets Swiss and Swiss2. I can do this manually in Latex but I need/want a direct hack in R so that my study is fully reproducible from the Rmarkdown file. Ideas anyone? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Could try editing the ploting function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `stargazer()` function, the row you refer to is governed by the `dep.var.caption` option. Unfortunately, since you want more than one column in this row, you can't accomplish what you want without some tinkering; if you pass a vector of length > 1 to this option, `stargazer()` will throw an error. So, we'll have to make a custom function that captures the output from `stargazer()` and modifies it accordingly before printing it.

The following .Rmd file worked fine for me (output below the code):

````
---
title: "Stack Overflow Answer"
author: "duckmayr"
date: "November 3, 2017"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
custom_table <- function(dataset_labels, ...) {
    tbl <- capture.output(stargazer::stargazer(...))
    pattern1 <- 'Dependent variable:'
    pattern2 <- '(?<= \\& ).+(?= \\\\)'
    first_row_index <- which(grepl(pattern=pattern1, x=tbl))
    first_row <- tbl[first_row_index]
    colspan <- as.numeric(gsub(pattern='[^0-9]+', replacement='', first_row))
    colspan <- colspan / length(dataset_labels)
    new_first_row <- sub('[0-9]+', colspan, first_row)
    replacement <- rep(stringr::str_extract(new_first_row, pattern2), 2)
    replacement <- stringr::str_replace(replacement, pattern1, dataset_labels)
    replacement <- paste(replacement, collapse=' & ')
    new_first_row <- stringr::str_replace(new_first_row, pattern2, replacement)
    new_first_row <- stringr::str_replace_all(new_first_row, 'multi', '\\\\multi')
    new_first_row <- stringr::str_replace_all(new_first_row, 'textit', '\\\\textit')
    tbl[first_row_index] <- new_first_row
    cat(tbl, sep='\n')
}
swiss2 <- swiss[1:20,]
m1 <- lm(Fertility ~ Agriculture, data = swiss)
m2 <- lm(Fertility ~ Examination, data = swiss)
m3 <- lm(Infant.Mortality ~ Education, data = swiss)
m4 <- lm(Infant.Mortality ~ Catholic, data = swiss)
m5 <- lm(Fertility ~ Agriculture, data = swiss2)
m6 <- lm(Fertility ~ Examination, data = swiss2)
m7 <- lm(Infant.Mortality ~ Education, data = swiss2)
m8 <- lm(Infant.Mortality ~ Catholic, data = swiss2)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
custom_table(c('Data: Swiss', 'Data: Swiss2'),
             m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8,
             type = "latex",
             header=FALSE,
             omit.stat=c("LL","ser","f","adj.rsq"), 
             font.size="tiny", 
             column.labels = c("(M1)", "(M2)", "(M3)", "(M4)", "(M5)", "(M6)", "(M7)", "(M8)"), 
             model.names = FALSE,
             model.numbers = FALSE,
             star.cutoffs = c(0.05, 0.01, 0.001),
             dep.var.labels = c("Outcome 1", "Outcome 2", "Outcome 1", "Outcome 2"))
```
````

[image]

EDIT:

If you'd prefer the output to go to a tex file rather than (or in addition to) directly using the output in the .Rmd file, we can make the following tweak:

```
custom_table <- function(dataset_labels, ..., cat_output=TRUE, out_file=NULL) {
    tbl <- capture.output(stargazer::stargazer(...))
    pattern1 <- 'Dependent variable:'
    pattern2 <- '(?<= \\& ).+(?= \\\\)'
    first_row_index <- which(grepl(pattern=pattern1, x=tbl))
    first_row <- tbl[first_row_index]
    colspan <- as.numeric(gsub(pattern='[^0-9]+', replacement='', first_row))
    colspan <- colspan / length(dataset_labels)
    new_first_row <- sub('[0-9]+', colspan, first_row)
    replacement <- rep(stringr::str_extract(new_first_row, pattern2), 2)
    replacement <- stringr::str_replace(replacement, pattern1, dataset_labels)
    replacement <- paste(replacement, collapse=' & ')
    new_first_row <- stringr::str_replace(new_first_row, pattern2, replacement)
    new_first_row <- stringr::str_replace_all(new_first_row, 'multi', '\\\\multi')
    new_first_row <- stringr::str_replace_all(new_first_row, 'textit', '\\\\textit')
    tbl[first_row_index] <- new_first_row
    if ( cat_output ) {
        cat(tbl, sep='\n')
    }
    if ( !is.null(out_file) ) {
        cat(tbl, sep='\n', file=out_file)
    }
}
```

Then if you run the code below in an R script, or put it in a chunk in an Rmd file, you will get the output written to the file 'test_out.tex' as well as directly output:

```
custom_table(c('Data: Swiss', 'Data: Swiss2'),
             out_file='test_out.tex',
             m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8,
             type = "latex",
             header=FALSE,
             omit.stat=c("LL","ser","f","adj.rsq"), 
             font.size="tiny", 
             column.labels = c("(M1)", "(M2)", "(M3)", "(M4)", "(M5)", "(M6)", "(M7)", "(M8)"), 
             model.names = FALSE,
             model.numbers = FALSE,
             star.cutoffs = c(0.05, 0.01, 0.001),
             dep.var.labels = c("Outcome 1", "Outcome 2", "Outcome 1", "Outcome 2"))
```

Using the `out` option of the `stargazer()` function won't quite work because `stargazer()` will write the output to `out` before we've had a chance to make our modifications to it, but this tweak works.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I can produce the proper output within R now but somehow it doesn't show up when I save the .tex file. I added `out="./table-custom.tex` in your `custom_table` function. Any ideas?

Comment: I've edited the answer to provide this functionality.